# Tex does not work in review

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

When I try to review a question/answer, most of the time Tex does not work. I do not know if this is a problem of my computer but I have no problem while looking at the questions. Do you have any idea?[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is because when you "expand" the view (from the snipplet to the full question), the display is re-written (to show you more text) but MathJax is not called again. This is not a problem on your end specifically.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks.

Comment: One work-around is to use Rob's ChatJaX solution available [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3297/21436)

Comment: We are aware of this issue and will investigate as time allows. Thanks!